# Java Regex with low letters underscore left, equal middle and any at right side

Tags: java, regex

im reading a file line for line and want only the lines like:

```
gui_test=Hallo
gui_test_hello=Hello
```

So on the left side are only small letter words separated by `_`. In the middle is always the `=` and on the right side can be any.

I made this regex:

```
^(([a-z]+_[a-z]+)+=.*)$
```

The Problem is, that it is working for

```
gui_pfc_button_ok=Ok!
```

But not working for:

```
gui_pfcuser_opportunitydetails_label_title=label Title
```

I don't know where my Problem is.

Comment: `^([a-z]+(?:_[a-z]+)*)=(.*)$`?

Comment: Your regex seems to work fine, what exactly is the issue?

       Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(([a-z]+_[a-z]+)+=.*)$");
       Matcher m = p.matcher("gui_pfc_button_ok=Ok!");
        System.out.println(m.matches());
        Matcher m2 = p.matcher("gui_pfcuser_opportunitydetails_label_title=label Title");
        System.out.println(m2.matches());

>> true
>> true

Comment: @PillHead

gui_pfcuser_opportunitydetails_message_title=Message Title

Sometimes it doesnt work randomly. For Example this one doesn't work for me in my junit tests... Can there be Problems with different Fonts?

Comment: @PillHead see my answer below. I've explained why you're not getting what you're expecting.

Comment: The syntax you are trying to parse looks like a properties file to me. Is there a reason not to use [java.util.Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Brief

The problem you're facing is that regex only captures the last match into the group (at least in most engines; .net is an exception here). You're using `([a-z]+_[a-z]+)+` and, while this is valid, you're only matching the last occurrence that matches this pattern, thus, you're only getting `l_title`. Since the match is greedy you're getting `l_` because the previous match took as many characters as it could. Breaking this down you're actually matching in the following way:

- `gui_pfcuse`
- `r_opportunitydetail`
- `s_labe`
- `l_title`

Your current regex will also fail if you only have 1 letter between underscores such as `something_here_a_test`. See your regex in use [here](https://regex101.com/r/qBD8f6/1)

---

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/qBD8f6/2)

```
^([a-z]+(?:_[a-z]+)*)=(.*)$
```

You can also use `^((?:[a-z]+_)*[a-z]+)=(.*)$` but it's less efficient (uses more steps than the regex above).

---

### Results

#### Input

```
gui_test=Hallo gui_test_hello=Hello
gui_pfcuser_opportunitydetails_label_title=label Title
gui_pfc_button_ok=Ok!
something_here_a_test=More words
```

#### Output

1. Match: `gui_test=Hallo gui_test_hello=Hello`

   - Group 1: `gui_test`
   - Group 2: `Hallo gui_test_hello=Hello`
2. Match: `gui_pfcuser_opportunitydetails_label_title=label Title`

   - Group 1: `gui_pfcuser_opportunitydetails_label_title`
   - Group 2: `label Title`
3. Match: `gui_pfc_button_ok=Ok!`

   - Group 1: `gui_pfc_button_ok`
   - Group 2: `Ok!`
4. Match: `something_here_a_test=More words`

   - Group 1: `something_here_a_test`
   - Group 2: `More words`

---

### Explanation

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `([a-z]+(?:_[a-z]+)*)` Capture the following into capture group 1

  - `[a-z]+` Match any lowercase ASCII letter one or more times
  - `(?:_[a-z]+)*` Match the following any number of times. If you require at least one match you can change `*` to `+` such that you end up with `(?:_[a-z]+)+`

    - `_` Match this literally
    - `[a-z]+` Match any lowercase ASCII letter one or more times
- `=` Match this literally
- `(.*)` Capture any character (except newline characters) into capture group 2
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

Answer (score 2):

```
^(([a-z]+_)+[a-z]+\=.*) $
```

Tested on https://regex101.com/ where the various parts are:

```
^          Asserts position at start of a line
([a-z]+_)+ One or more sequences of the form <one_or_more_lower_case>_
[a-z]+     One or more lower case letter
\= escaped equals sign
.*         zero or more characters
$          end of line
```

Comment: This won't catch the last instance of `[a-z]+`

Comment: Was the initial requirement to capture, or just match?

Comment: I think it's to capture considering the OP was already matching the full string. Their pattern does work, but it's only working on the match and not capturing each side of the `=`

Answer (score 2):

Just move your underscore into the character class brackets, and you're home. You can remove the + for the inner group as well if you want...

```
^(([a-z]+[_a-z]+)=.*)$
```

If you want, you can try it out at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/H9pWvk/1).

If you don't want to match lines with two consecutive underscores, you can group on the underscore part, in pseudocode `xxx(_xxx)*`, which would then become

```
^([a-z]+(_[a-z]+)*+=.*)$
```

Also testable at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/H9pWvk/2).

Comment: This would allow consecutive underscores, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes... Updating ;-)